# How can I read URL parameters in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a blog using AngularJS. The home page queries a third party service of mine that returns an array of all my articles/posts. I am displaying shortened versions of these posts on the home page, and want to have "read more" under each post that passes that post's ID through a URL parameter to another HTML page:

**index.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="blogCtrl" id="blog">
    <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <div class="header"> 
        <h1>{{ post.fields.title }}</h1>
        <p class="date">{{ post.sys.createdAt | date}}</p>
      </div> 

      <p>{{ post.fields.body | cut:true:1600:' ...'}}</p>

      <a href="post.html?id={{ post.sys.id }}">read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What do I need to do in `post.html` so that I can read the value of `id` in the URL parameter? Do I need to create a new angularJS app in `post.html`?

edit:

I've changed the read more link to `<a href="post/{{post.sys.id}}">` and i am trying to set up the following route:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/post/:postid',{
    templateUrl: '/post.html',
    controller: 'postCtrl' 
  })
});
```

However, clicking the "read more" link doesn't load up `post.html`, but instead a page that says `File not found: /post/2B1K9K2DHqsYaGYcms2YeW`. The route doesn't seem to be getting properly set up, since `post.html` isn't getting loaded.

Comment: you *can* create a new angular app in the `post.html` page, but the better method is to use a router, like angular router or ui-router to handle routing and use angular as a Single Page Application (SPA).  In this way, you don't have a different page called post.html.

Comment: in fact, there are more elegant ways to handle the `read more` link that wouldn't even require a new page.

Comment: I'm definitely considering having an SPA style blog, but for the time being, and for learning purposes, i would like the individual posts to have their own pages. Is it possible to use angular routing with a single angular app and have multiple html pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't all that hard to do, but you need to have routing set up on your app.  You can create this functionality in your existing app, or separate it into a new one, it's up to you.  Here are the relevant things you'll need to include in your code:

In your app include ngRoute as a dependency:

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);`

Also include routing config for your app:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/someroute', {
            templateUrl: 'someFolder/withSomeFile.html'
        }
        .when('/someroutewithparamters/:aftercolonisparameter', {
            templateUrl: 'someFolder/post.html'
        }

});
```

You can include a default route as well, but it's not necessary if you'd rather not.  Be sure to include angular-route.js in your index.html for this to work.

Now in your controller you can simply do something like:

```
myApp.controller('postCtrl', function($routeParams, $scope, postFactory){

     $scope.post = postFactory.functionToLoadPost($routeParams.aftercolonisparameter);

});
```

Obviously this will be different for your implementation based on how everything is set up, and you'll probably want to pick better names for your elements than I did, but those are the things you'll need in place to make this work.  It's actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: I tried adding a route similar to your second route. I can't seem to implement it however. I've edited my original post, can you tell me why it may not be working?

Comment: I think my problem may be that I'm trying to incorporate this method into a multi-page website. Is this routing only for single-page angular apps?

Comment: Did you include the angular-route file in your index.html, or whatever file contains the ng-app attribute?  Like this: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter.  As long as the app is calling a function it has access to and the post id is valid for the DB where you're storing it, it doesn't matter how many angular apps you're running on the site.  As long as this one is configured correctly.

Comment: Yes, i made sure to include that.

Comment: I see the problem.  Look at when().  The templateurl needs to be inside the parenthesis.  Also make sure you include the proper controller on that post.html page.

Comment: Yes, just realized that. I made the fix, now I'm seeing a different problem. It's not loading up post.html. It's loading a page that says `File Not Found

/post/2B1K9K2DHqsYaGYcms2YeW`

Comment: Right, but this should be after an Angular url.  So, `yoursite.com/#/post/2B1K9K2DHqsYaGYcms2YeW`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding your point with the last comment. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: You probably need to look further into how Angular works.  If you're using a separate app for this one page (which defeats the purpose of Angular), then your route might be `/:postid` rather than `/post/:postid`, but either way your content will load via a url like so: `yoursite.com/post.html#2B1K9K2DHqsYaGYcms2YeW`.  This is how Angular's routing system works, if you're having trouble with it you should look at the documentation.  Also, this is a basic concept in HTML you should be familiar with as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely just starting out in angular so thank you for bearing with me. I don't have a separate app for `post.html`. I only have one angular app right now and all the javascript I've posted so far is inside that app. Is it possible for post.html to get loaded as a separate page while still staying within my single angular app? Or do I have to go with a SPA?

Comment: Are you piecing this all together yourself, or are you following some type of tutorial.  At the very least you should read the Angular documentation on ngRoute to understand what it's doing.  You can also look at this tutorial given at angularjs.org: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial - Step 7 covers routing.  To explain it all here would be a bit too much/beyond the scope of the site.  You could do it without making it a single page app, but if you read the documentation and get more familiar you'll start to see why a SPA is can be just as robust, which is why angular is so powerful.